# Why is margin top not working on an image replacement logo?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu splited by the logo:

```
 <div id="header">
    <div id="header-container">

       <div class="left-nav">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Awards</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="logo">
        <h1>Magdi Designs</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="right-nav">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 #header {
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 30px;
 }

 #header-container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
 }

 #header li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 60px;
 }

 #header .left-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }

 #header h1 {
    background: url(logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 284px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
 }

 #header .right-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
 }
```

The `<h1>` logo tag doesn't seem to apply the margin top.
Sorry if I'm putting too much irrelevant code, but I'm not sure what's causing the problem.
I've also tried padding but still doesn't work.
jsFiddle Demo

Secondary question:
Is this a good way to do the split menu?

Comment: Create fiddles when you ask such questions http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cG6Nm/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#header h1 {
    margin: 15px auto 0;
}
```

instead of:

```
#header h1 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `margin: auto` after `margin-top: 15px` which is removing the desired margin. The `margin: auto` isn't needed anyway.

Comment: still no top margin even with removing the margin:auto :/

Comment: You've also got the issue of collapsing margins with the margin-top on `#header`. [See here for more info](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).
I'd probably be putting padding-top on `#header` instead of a margin-top on the logo anyway.